# Laravel Route Php Apache VirtualHost no funciona

Tags: laravel, rutas, virtualhost

Hola mi problema radica en que no he encontrado la solución a mi problema de rutas en Laravel, pasa que cuando entro a una ruta que es public/empleados por ejemplo me sale el error 404

Ya intenté lo del VirtualHost pero sigue sin funcionar, ese es mi código

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xxampp/htdocs/Code/Laravel/sistema/public"  
ServerName laravel.com 
ServerAlias demo.laravel.com</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xxampp/htdocs/Code/Laravel/sistema/public"  
ServerName sistema.com 
ServerAlias demo.sistema.com</VirtualHost>
```

Entonces ese es mi código de httpd.config

y este del host en system32

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   127.0.0.1       yoursite.local
#   ::1             localhost
#   127.0.0.1       sistema.com
    127.0.0.1      laravel.com
```

Ya no encontré mas soluciones, si alguien sabe, ayudeme, se lo agradecería mucho para continuar con mi curso de Laravel

Comment: ¿No será porque tienes `xxampp` en vez de `xampp`?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que instale primeramente un xampp pero lo borré y quedó la carpeta con varios proyectos entonces llamé a la nueva carpeta xxampp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal vez esto le sirva a alguien mas mi problema era el siguiente, yo tengo apache en el puerto 8080, lo cambié una vez que no encontraba el error que tenía en el puerto 80 ya que este puerto es muy solicitado, entonces mi problema se solucionó agregando :8080, literalmente eso fue todo, les dejó el código que estoy usando para el host virtual

En host estoy usando este código

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       larvel.com.test
```

En el archivo de httpv estoy usando este otro código

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
  DocumentRoot "C:\xxampp\htdocs\Code"
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
  DocumentRoot "C:\xxampp\htdocs\Code\Laravel\sistema\public"
  ServerName larvel.com.test
  ServerAlias www.larvel.com.test
  <Directory "C:\xxampp\htdocs\Code\Laravel\sistema\public">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Y este es el url que estoy usando

larvel.com.test:8080/

Muchas gracias, espero les ayude :D